# Absolute Angular Velocity - How to use?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, kinetic-theory

From my dynamics course, we were introduced to the so-called absolute angular velocity of a rigid body. Below is a short diagram:

[image]

The following equation for the velocity of point P on a rigid body is therefore:

[image]

There is also the so-called chain rule we learned from our tutorial exercises:

[image]

So after that short introduction, let me introduce the problem I have with a certain exercise:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why the absolute velocity vector (highlighted in green) is the sum of the disk's absolute velocity and the rod's absolute velocity?

I though if we were using the chain rule like they did there, you only needed the absolute velocity of the disk (or rather the angular velocity of ηξζ-CoSy since I assume it's body fixed to the disk) for the disk part since the angular velocity of the rod is already considered in the velocity equation using the chain rule via absolute velocity of B (highlighted in yellow)

Comment: https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/rotations/kinematics_rotation.html and the links therein

Answer (score 0):

I will obtain it like this

$$\vec v_p=\vec \omega\times \vec r_{AB}+
\left(\vec \omega+\vec\Omega\right)\times \vec r+\vec v_{rel}$$

with

\begin{align*}
  &  \vec{\omega}=\begin{bmatrix}
                    0\\
                    0 \\
                    \omega
                 \end{bmatrix}\quad,
 \vec{\Omega}=\begin{bmatrix}
                    0\\
                    0 \\
                    \Omega
                  \end{bmatrix}\\
&\vec{r}_{AB}=\begin{bmatrix}
                \rho\,\cos(\phi)\\
                \rho\,\sin(\phi) \\
                0 \\
              \end{bmatrix},\quad
\vec{r}=\begin{bmatrix}
                \rho\,\cos(\phi)\\
                -\rho\,\sin(\phi) \\
                0 \\
              \end{bmatrix} \\
&\vec{v}_{\rm rel}=\begin{bmatrix}
                v\,\cos(\phi)\\
                -v\,\sin(\phi) \\
                0 \\
              \end{bmatrix}                           
\end{align*}

$\Rightarrow$

\begin{align*}
  & \vec{v}_p=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\omega\,\rho\,\sin \left( \varphi  \right)
+ \left( \omega+\Omega \right) r\sin \left( \varphi  \right) +v\cos
 \left( \varphi  \right) \\\omega\,\rho\,\cos
 \left( \varphi  \right) + \left( \omega+\Omega \right) r\cos \left(
\varphi  \right) -v\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\0
\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}

the acceleration

assume that $~v~$ is constant and $~\omega~$ is constant
\begin{align*}
 &\vec{a}_p=\frac{d}{dt}\vec{v}_p=
 \frac{\partial \vec{v}_p}{\partial \Omega}\,\underbrace{\dot{\Omega}}_{\alpha}+
  \frac{\partial \vec{v}_p}{\partial r}\,\underbrace{\dot{r}}_{v}\\
 &\vec{a}_p= \left[ \begin {array}{c}  \left( \omega+\Omega \right) \sin \left(
\varphi  \right) v+r\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \alpha
\\ \left( \omega+\Omega \right) \cos \left(
\varphi  \right) v+r\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \alpha
\\0\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}